# R - create list with levels

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a dataframe with large number of categorical variables. I need to create a list, where I would get the output similar to str(DF), but not truncated

Example:

```
 Df <- data.frame(
   x = as.factor(sample(1:5,30,r=T)),
   y = as.factor(sample(1:5,30,r=T)),
   z = as.factor(sample(1:5,30,r=T)),
   w = as.factor(sample(1:5,30,r=T))
)
str(Df)
```

produces output like this:

```
x: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..:
```

But this is insufficient for me, both because I need all levels, and because I have a large number of variables in the dataframe, so I also get the "  [list output truncated]: message...

Ideal thing is to get what levels(Df$x) does for each variable.
I hoped for this code to work:

```
attach(Df)
idnames <- names(Df)
levellist <- lapply(idnames, function(x) levels(x))
##
```

but it returns NULL for all variables..

Answer (score 1):

`levels` works on factors, so use it on `Df`, which is a list of factors.

```
levellist <- lapply(Df, function(x) levels(x))
```